# How do I overcome "Operation not permitted" when attempting to edit a file as root (admin)?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, permission, filesystem, root

I'm using Mac 10.13.6.  I want to add environment variables to be recognized by my Apache instance.  However, I'm not able to edit the file, event when logged in as root ...

```
localhost:Documents davea$ sudo touch /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
touch: setting times of '/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist': Operation not permitted
```

I was reading here -- https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/ that I have to take some additional steps to allow access to certain files, but when I go to my Privacy settings, I don't see any option for unlocking "Full Disk Access" ...

[image]

All I want to do is edit my "/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist" file.  What do I need to do to make this possible?

Comment: Is there a less invasive way to set environment variables that Apache can reference?

Comment: You can edit it in Recovery Mode: `some_command /Volumes/Main_Volume_Name/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist` or use another Apache (e.g. brew installed Apache)